# A 'different' explanation to "Supremum"

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

While the definition of "Supremum" is not alien to me, my lecturer uses a different approach to the definition of "supremum", of which I am unable to grasp. 
If someone could shed some light, that'll be perfect.

To be more specific, I'm not understanding why B' and s > B' is being used here.

Comment: Different from what? What is your definition of the supremum?

Comment: Suppose S is a subset of R and Sup(S) = B is the least upper bound
1) then B >= to x for all x in S
2) there exists some B' >= to B

So we have x <= B <= B'

Comment: It is basically saying, for any real number $B'$ less than $B$, $B'$ is not an upper bound of $S$ because you can always find an element $s$ of $S$ that is larger than $B'$. In other words $B$ is the smallest possible upper bound of $S$.

Comment: anything greater than B is also an upper bound

Comment: Your definition works for any upper bound other than $+\infty$, @guest. You can choose $B'=B+1$. The point of the $B'$ in the definition above is to ensure that $B$ is the least upper bound.

Comment: Replace the word "sup" with "max", those two aren't the same thing, but it's the best way to understand "sup"

Answer (score 1):

$B$ is an upper bound of $S$ if for every $s\in S$ one has $B\ge s$. So the statement

> there exists $s\in S$ such that $s>B'$

means that $B'$ is not an upper bound. So the second condition reads:

> for all $B'<B$, $B'$ is not an upper bound

which is the perfect translation of "$B$ is the *least* upper bound".